# Execute for- loop only twice

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

How to execute a for-loop only twice. For example:

```
for (Product products : productList) {
}
```

Product List has 3 items inside it, so by default it will loop 3 times. But I want to loop it only 2 times.

Can anyone help me out with the solution.

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe you have done even the slightest research.

Comment: I did some research that I can limit the list size as 2 , but it didn't work

Comment: @StackQuest Define "didn't work."

Answer (score 2):

Use a traditional `for` loop on the first two elements like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    Product products = productList.get(i);
    // ...
}
```

**or** use the `for-each` on a [`subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) like

```
for (Product products : productList.subList(0, 2)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use increment loop for this as well;

```
for(int i= 0 ; i<productList.length();i++)
{
  Product products = productList.get(i);
  if (i>1)
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `Java 8+` users, [`limit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-) can be used for this scenario.

Considering you have a Product class:

```
public class Product {
    
    String name;

    public Product(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
    products.add(new Product("Shoes"));
    products.add(new Product("Shawarma"));
    products.add(new Product("Hummus"));

    products.stream()
            .limit(2)
            .forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getName())); //Prints out only two products shoes and shawarma
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
//your code for operate with products
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.